# Assignment by logical indexing in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, variable-assignment

I have a real-valued `numpy` array of size `(1000,)`. All values lie between 0 and 1, and I want to convert this to a categorical array. All values less than 0.25 should be assigned to category 0, values between 0.25 and 0.5 to category 1, 0.5 to 0.75 to category 2, and 0.75 to 1 to category 3. Logical indexing doesn't seem to work:

```
Y[Y < 0.25] = 0
Y[np.logical_and(Y >= 0.25, Y < 0.5)] = 1
Y[np.logical_and(Y >= 0.5, Y < 0.75)] = 2
Y[Y >= 0.75] = 3
```

Result:

```
for i in range(4):
    print(f"Y == {i}: {sum(Y == i)}")

Y == 0: 206
Y == 1: 0
Y == 2: 0
Y == 3: 794
```

What needs to be done instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in your conversion logic, not in your indexing.  The final statment:

```
Y[Y >= 0.75] = 3
```

Converts not only the values in range 0.75 - 1.00, but also the prior assignments to classes 1 and 2.

You can reverse the assignment order, starting with class 3.

You can put an upper limit on the final class, although you still have a boundary problem with 1.00 vs class 1.

Perhaps best would be to harness the regularity of your divisions, such as:

```
Y = int(4*Y)    # but you still have boundary problems.
```

Comment: I need more sleep... Thanks.